# A problem about congruence subgroups

Tags: group-theory, modular-forms

Let $N$ be the greatest common divisor of $N_1$ and $N_2$, is it true that there exists a [congruence subgroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_subgroup) containing $\Gamma(N_1)$ and $\Gamma(N_2)$ but not containing $\Gamma(N)$, where $$\Gamma(N)=\ker(SL_2(\Bbb{Z}) \to SL_2(\Bbb{Z}/(N)))$$ is the full congruence subgroup of level $N$.

If $(N_1,N_2)=1$, then $\Gamma(N_1)$ and $\Gamma(N_2)$ can generate $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})=\Gamma(1)$, thus the proposition is not true in this case, but I do not know the general case.

Comment: What is a congruent subgroup? Perhaps including the definition with an [edit] to your question might attract more potential users with answers.

Comment: Also, it is not immediately clear what your question is.

Comment: Note that there exist integers $a,b$ such that $aN_1+bN_2=N$, and then
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & N_1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}^a
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & N_2 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}^b
=
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & N \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
I suspect one can use variations on this theme to show that $\Gamma(N)$ is always contained in the group generated by $\Gamma(N_1)$ and $\Gamma(N_2)$.

Comment: For any $g$ coprime with $N_2/N$ the map $\Gamma(g N)\to \Gamma(N)/\Gamma(N_2)\subset SL_2(\Bbb{Z}/(N_2))$ is surjective which implies $\Gamma(N)= \bigcup_j \alpha_j \Gamma(N_2)$ with $\alpha_j \in  \Gamma(gN)$ @GregMartin